# Sharepoint 2010 list form edited using Infopath

Tags: list

we have a list whose forms(newform.aspx,editform.aspx,displayform.aspx) has been modified using infopath, how can i change it either back to listformwebpart or replace with custom list form..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to List -> List Settings -> Form Settings.

You will get options to use default list settings and delete InfoPath Form settings.